# $(X,A)$, $(Y,B)$, $(X \times Y, A \otimes B)$ measurable spaces. How to show $A=\{\emptyset, X\}$ or $B=\{\emptyset, Y\}$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

like the title said, I want to show that $A=\{\emptyset, X\}$ or $B=\{\emptyset, Y\}$ if $(X,A)$, $(Y,B)$, $(X \times Y, A \otimes B)$ are measurable spaces.

I tried to form a contradiction by assuming there exists an element neither $\emptyset$ nor X in A but it didn't work or I just didn't understand it.

If you could help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you think about the case of that X and Y are Real line. Then AxB consists only of rectangles. The union of two different rectangles is not a rectangle.

Comment: If you want to start with the contradiction you get a proper nonempty measurable subset in X and in Y.

Comment: I don't understand this topic yet. So sorry for taking a liong time understanding. I start by assuming there exists A* in A. But how do I go from there? AxB are the pairs (a,b) in AxB, aren't they?

Comment: You got the Elements of AxB right. We want to show that A or B consist only of the empty set or X(or Y). So we can assume that both of them have a non trivial set A* and B*.

Comment: We assumed $\emptyset \subsetneq A* \subsetneq X, \emptyset \subsetneq B* \subsetneq Y$. Now we have that $(A*,B*) \in A \otimes B$. I don't see a contradiction since A*, B*are subsets and therefore in $X \times Y$ :(

Comment: If A* is in A then X\A is in A. Simililarily X\B is in B. Think about the case of the plane, where the union of two rectangles is not a rectangle.

Comment: I can visualize the problem for myself now, like you said, we wouldn't get a rectangle. If we had X\A* in A and Y\B* in B, then X\A* $\times$ Y\B* should be in $\sigma (A \times B). I don't know how one should write it in a proper mathematical manner

Comment: Find in the union of the rectangles Elements (a, b) and (c, d) such that (a, d) is not in the union of the rectangles.

Comment: Hey, I wrote $A \otimes B = \{\emptyset, (a,b), (a,d), (a,Y), (c,b), (c,d), (c,Y), (X,b), (X,d), (X,Y)\}$ where c=X\a = X\A* and d = Y\b = Y\B*. I can't seem to find such a union. I thought about arguing that the complement of (a,Y) = $(c, \emptyset)$ is not in $A \otimes B$ but that's not a union